# Will we at least know that the electron passes through only one slit in the case its wave function collapses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment

Will we at least know that the electron passes through only one slit in the case its wave function collapses due to presence of detectors in the double slit experiment? When there is a clump pattern formed on the screen do we know that all the traces on the left part of the screen came from the left slit and all of them on the right part of the screen derive from the right slit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we do know that.

If we are willing to collapse the wavefunction of the particle, by measuring its position, then we can in principle measure the position of it instant by instant: meaning that we can effectively observe its *trajectory*.
But of course this procedure comes at the cost of the collapse of the wavefunction, and the subsequent absence of quantum interference phenomena.